# I need help getting the "Text Entry" notification bar icon back (the one that changes keyboard input method)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, nvidia, software-installation, language-support

The `Text Entry` selection button (i.e. the button that swaps between language keyboard input types) on the top menu bar is missing. It was there a few days ago, but now the button on the menu bar to choose the `Text Entry` input method is gone. Please help me get it back.

[image: The Text Entry notification icon is gone.]

[Original Image Uploaded by OP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83i1a.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to fix, simply do the following:

1. Open up the Dash menu and type `Text Entry` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   [image: Pick text entry from the dash menu.]
2. You will see the following application open.

   [image: Text Entry application.]
3. Make sure the checkbox for `Show current input source in the menu bar` is ticked (see picture below).

   [image: Checkbox that needs to be selected.]
4. Also make sure the languages you want to switch between is listed in the box (in my example I have `English (UK)` and `Arabic`).

   [image: Languages installed.]
5. If your languages are not in the list, add them using the <kbd>+</kbd> button.

   [image: Plus button to click on.]
6. Select your language and then press <kbd>Add</kbd>.

   [image: Language selection.]